# Open-source blockchain explorer for regtest mode

Tags: regtest, blockchain-explorer

I'm trying to find an open-source Bitcoin blockchain explorer that will work in *regtest mode*, so I can more easily inspect the blockchain, see what transactions are getting processed and included, etc.

I found the following ones, but all of them seem to have issues:

- [blockcypher](https://github.com/blockcypher/explorer) is *"not easily compatible with running your own version locally, and this is no longer recommended (except for expert users)."*
- [bitcoinchain](https://bitcoinchain.com/about-us) is not open-source AFAICT.
- Bitcore's insight-ui [[1]](https://github.com/bitcoin-blockexplorer), [[2]](https://insight.bitpay.com/), [[3]](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-ui) does not work with `bitcoind` AFAICT.
- [toshi](https://github.com/coinbase/toshi) does not work with `bitcoind` AFAICT. Not sure how to set it up in regtest mode to connect to another `bitcoind` full node.
- [bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) does not seem to support regtest mode, though it could be as easy as adding a new `Abe/Chain/Regtest.py` file.
- [blockchain.info](https://github.com/blockchain): can't really tell if the *My-Wallet-V3-** repos [[1]](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet-V3-Frontend), [[2]](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet-V3) are for the block explorer website or for the wallet-management side of the website.

So, any suggestions for an easy-to-setup blockchain explorer that works with a local `bitcoind` node ?

Comment: Great list however, Toshi doesn't really have much to do with Bitcoin and is not an explorer AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to point Abe to regtest just by using datadir=/home/$USER/.bitcoin/regtest in the config file and following the official instructions.

Comment: worked fine. there is a bug with segwit `MerkleRootMismatch: Block header Merkle root does not match its transactions. block hash=0000000000`. i solved it by cloning `https://github.com/marioschlipf/bitcoin-abe` repo

Answer (score 1):

I tried Abe but couldn't easily make it work on MacOS. I had a look at some other options and managed to make this one https://github.com/janoside/btc-rpc-explorer work easily and nicely. It has quite a lot of things you want from an explorer.

Answer (score 0):

**Bitcoin Abe is awsome.**

create virtual environment for python2.7(since abe only work with python2.x)::

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv, python-dev
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 myenv
```

Install requirements:

```
source ./myenv/bin/activate
pip install pycrypto
```

clone [marioschlipf's repo](https://github.com/marioschlipf/bitcoin-abe) (since it solves segwit) and install it::

```
git clone https://github.com/marioschlipf/bitcoin-abe
cd bitcoin-abe
python setup.py install
```

Create `abe.conf` with contents:

```
datadir=/home/USER/.bitcoin/regtest
dbtype sqlite3
connect-args abe.sqlite
upgrade
port 2750
```

Perform the initial data load:

```
python -m Abe.abe --config abe.conf --commit-bytes 100000 --no-serve
```

Look for output such as:

```
block_tx 1 1
```

Then run the web server as:

```
python -m Abe.abe --config abe.conf
```

Now vist on browser http://localhost:2750